# TableView selected background view switching orientations

Tags: iphone, uitableview, landscape

I have a nib file that contains the view at 320 wide for portrait mode and it works fine.

cell.selectedBackgroundView = aView

I set the auto resize mask to allow the tableview to expand in landscape mode like so:

setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];

but this does not expand the highlight view that remains at 320!

How do I get the highlight view to expand as well as the table view?

I have tried this:

[cell setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];

but no good???

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`selectedBackgroundView` is a `UIView` too, meaning that it might help to `aView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth` too.

Cheers!

Comment: What type of view is your `aView`?  If it is a custom view it may not be resizing automatically.